# Block all traffic except for Chrome

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall

I will be working on my 3G connection for a few days (meaning I'll be in the middle of nowhere). I don't want Windows to update and don't want any of my apps and services to connect to internet. I will be using only Chrome. I'm just trying to block all outgoing traffic with Windows Firewall and adding an Allow rule for Chrome but I suppose Block overrides Allow. So is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** (Because I was asked to provide "essential parts"): [TripMode](https://www.tripmode.ch/tripmode-for-windows-released/) should be exactly what you are looking for.

TripMode is able to stop updates and other background processes from consuming your data. You can select specific apps and only allow them to connect to the internet. You can buy it or use it for free 15 minutes/day.

(I use it a lot on my Mac, there it works perfectly for the tasks you mentioned)